# Creating class instances by variables with Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to convert the following piece of code to work with Typescript?

```
public shops: string[] = [
   "AShop",
   "BShop",
   "CShop",
];    

this.shops.forEach((shop, index) => {
    let instance = new window[shop](index);
    this.instances.push(instance);
});
```

The following approach doesn't work with `Typescript` because `window` is inexistent in the scope. I cannot compile it. (Although it would work with vanilla JS)

Is there a way to treat variable name `shop` in the loop as an expression and create a dynamic class based on it?

Comment: Where is defined `purchasable`?

Comment: @timocov Oops, fixed it. It was meant to be shop.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Do you have `noImplicitAny` compiler option enabled?

Comment: Try this:
```class BaseShop { }
interface ShopContructor {
 new (index: number): BaseShop;
}
interface Window {
 [shop: string]: ShopContructor;
}```

Comment: You need to use type declarations to inform the compiler that you expect those constructors to exist on `window`.

Comment: @timocov Yes. I'll give it a try. Can you post it as an answer so I can pick it as the answer if it works?

Comment: @timocov I gave it a try, couldn't get it to work. I tried setting `noImplicitAny` to false too, no luck.

Comment: @Aris What concretely does not work? You get an error or what?

Comment: @timocov When I set `noImplicitAny` to false, it compiles but I get an `Uncaught TypeError: window[shop] is not a constructor`. I didn't understand your other answer.

Comment: So, the problem is not in TypeScript :) You have no constructor in `window[purchasable]`

Comment: @timocov Yes, it is because those classes are not global on `window`. What about your trick, though? Can you try that on `http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/`?

Comment: Try to create a new variable out of the loop which will be your window: `let test = window;` Then try to access your dynamic class like `let instance = new test[shop](index);`

Comment: Sorry for that :-( It is compiled fine in typescript playground
```const shops: string[] = [
   "AShop",
   "BShop",
   "CShop",
];
class BaseShop { }
interface ShopContructor {
 new (index: number): BaseShop;
}
interface Window {
 [shop: string]: ShopContructor;
}
const instances: BaseShop[] = [];
shops.forEach((shop: string, index: number) => {
    let instance = new window[shop](index);
    instances.push(instance);
});
```

Comment: @timocov I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: window[shop] is not a constructor` on Typescript playground. Can I get a link to your working example?

Comment: Of course you will get this error because you do not set it to window.

Comment: @Aris link is too long to post it as comment here

Comment: @timocov URL shortener maybe? :)

Comment: @Aris It is forbidden by stackoverflow

Comment: @timocov Maybe you can write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const shops: string[] = ["AShop", "BShop", "CShop"];

class BaseShop {
    public constructor(index: number) {
        console.log(index);
    }
 }

class AShop extends BaseShop { }
class BShop extends BaseShop { }
class CShop extends BaseShop { }

interface ShopContructor {
    new (index: number): BaseShop;
}

interface Window {
    AShop: ShopContructor;
    BShop: ShopContructor;
    CShop: ShopContructor;
    [shop: string]: ShopContructor;
}

window.AShop = AShop;
window.BShop = BShop;
window.CShop = CShop;

const instances: BaseShop[] = [];

shops.forEach((shop: string, index: number) => {
    let instance = new window[shop](index);
    instances.push(instance);
});

console.log(instances);
```

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of `window.AShop = AShop;`? I would rather rely on a switch/case actually. Just wanted a magic trick to initialize all the array as a class.

Comment: You can add all classes to an array (instead of their names). `const shops: ShopContructor[] = [AShop, BShop, CShop];`

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird structure, because if you have dynamic classes in the global scope you can't get good type checking for it at compile time. I'd suggest just using `<any>` here and getting it over with. If you expect certain type guarantees for the resulting instance, you should specify them explicitly using the variable type or casting:

```
this.shops.forEach((shop, index) => {
    let instance = new (<any>window)[shop](index);
    this.instances.push(instance);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: window[shop] is not a function :(

Comment: @Aris But I don't have `window[shop]` in this code. I changed it to `(<any>window)[shop]`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin `(<any>window)[shop]` is compiled to `window[shop]`

Comment: @timocov Ah, I didn't realize this was a runtime error! So the OP doesn't even have the constructor functions in the global scope? Where are they?